# Imacros. How to use TAG to write content to an Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, imacros

How to use TAG to write content to an Editable DIV in imacros firefox?
I need help
How can I write in div?
help please!
as in picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvOxC.jpg

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=ID:posting_form_text_field
```

```html
<div id="posting_form_text_field" class="itx itx__ce ok-e textWrap js-focus" contenteditable="true">textexemple...</div>
```

Comment: Record your macro in Experimental event recording mode.

Comment: I want to write in that frame

as in picture: http://imgur.com/a/70JnD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
SET text "Some my text here"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#posting_form_text_field" CHARS={{text}}
```

Comment: not always work
if the browser is not open, do not work
why?

Comment: Unfortunately, on some pages the event commands work like that :(